# I would like to normalize my json data on server side for XSS prevention. Am i doing it the right way?

Tags: php, json, ajax, security, xss

I am implementing the XSS prevention cheat rules in my app and I currently working on escaping/securing Json data and wondering if I am doing it right?

According to [Rule 3.1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse) in the [XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse) "An alternative to escaping and unescaping JSON directly in JavaScript, is to normalize JSON server-side by converting '<' to '\u003c' before delivering it to the browser."

So I have created a function in php called normalizeJson which takes in an associative array as a parameter and converts all < characters to \u003c, returning the data in json format.
I am wondering if this is the best way to do this?

I'm unsure as to whether it is ok to json_encode twice here however it didn't work when I had `return $new_json` (without json_encoding it again.)

```
function normalizeJson($data){
    $json = json_encode($data);
    $new_json = str_replace("<","\u003c",$data);
    return json_encode($new_json);
}
```

Also it states in [the same rule](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse), "read the data with JSON.parse" however when I use the `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` in my ajax request and try parse the response with `JSON.parse(data)` it doesn't work.

It works perfect without `JSON.parse()`. I'm guessing this is because it is expecting json as a response anyway and so doesn't need to parse it with `JSON.parse()` but I would like clarification on this if anyone knows.

Client side Ajax request:

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("usertoken");  
var params = {'usertoken': token, 'engage_post_text' : engage_post_text, 'post_type' : post_type};  
$.ajax({
    //do an ajax request passing along the user json web token for validation on server side and also the text that was submitted.
        url: app_root_url + 'submit_post.php',
        data: JSON.stringify(params), 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
        var result = data;//JSON.parse(data);

        var successful_insert = result.successful_insert;
        if(successful_insert){
            //do stuff with json data
        }else{
            //error 
        }
    }
});
```

My php code where the ajax request is sent, and I use the normalizeJson function before returing the json back to the client side.

```
//need to get the data this way because we have contentType application/json set, so $_POST will no longer be populated
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($rawPostData);

if(isset($json->usertoken)){
    $token = JWT::decode($json->usertoken, 'secret_server_key'); //this will return an error if token has been tampered with    
    $data = array();
    if($token->userID){
        //token is valid and therefore user is valid so we go ahead submit the form.
        $data['token_is_valid'] = true;

        if(isset($json->engage_post_text)){ 
            $postText = $json->engage_post_text;
            $postType = filter_var($json->post_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $postTime = time();
            $user_id = $token->userID;

            $result = insertEngagePost($postTime, $user_id, $postText, $postType, $pdoConnection);
            if($result['successful_insert'] == true){
                $data['successful_insert'] = true;
                $data['post_id'] = $result['post_id'];
                $data['userDetails'] = getProfile($user_id, $pdoConnection);        
            }else{
                $data['successful_insert'] = false;     
            }
            //send back json to client side ajax request
            echo normalizeJson($data);
        }

    }else{
        //token is set but is not valid
        $data['token_is_valid'] = false;
        echo normalizeJson($data);
    }   
}else{
    //token is not set.     
}
```

Comment: While escaping everything server side can be done, I would argue that the alternative method here isn't a good idea. You can just use textContent instead of innerHTML when displaying the response and then you don't need to worry about encoding problems.

Comment: ok thanks for your advice. But I thought there was a concern that the json "data" I receive back in my ajax request, could contain unintended script tags which could be executed when coming back to the ajax response (causing XSS attack). is this correct? I'm just getting used to how XSS works. thanks... the other thing is (regarding what you said about inserting to html) when I insert the data to the html, I do it using the ESAPI javascript library like so: var safe_comment_text = $ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(result.commentText); 
'<p class="text_of_comment">' + safe_comment_text + '</p>'

Comment: When you make a XMLHttpRequest (which is what jQuery's $.ajax method does), the response will not be automatically parsed, so there is no danger of the response being parsed for <script> tags unless you append it to the page, which it looks like you are doing in a safe way (I am not familiar with the $ESAPI package)

Comment: thanks. just doing a test now and I put this in my php script $data = '<script>alert(123)</script>'; echo json_encode($data); unfortunately the alert did* execute when sent back to the ajax request. :/

Comment: Well yea, if you go to that page in your browser it will execute. Try calling the page with your Ajax script.

Comment: sorry my bad. I had it inserting into html when coming back. thats why it executed. ok that clears it up. thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129114/discussion-between-gerrit0-and-sarah).